# In Presto how to retrieve an array with unique elements

Tags: sql, presto

I have a query

`SELECT id, id_arr from RESULTS`

and it returns a result like this:

```
    123             [742] 
    123             [332,180]
    123             [742,180,039] 
    123             [244,302, 742] 
    123             [412]
```

How in Presto to construct a query that yields me the ID and the combined array with only its unique elements?  I know about the ARRAY_UNION function but am having problems getting it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also try aggregating the array and finding the distinct elements within using the following:

```sql
SELECT
    id, 
    set_union(id_arr) as combined_id_arr
FROM
    RESULTS
GROUP BY 
    id
```

OR more verbose

```sql
SELECT
    id, 
    array_distinct(flatten(array_agg(id_arr))) as combined_id_arr
FROM
    RESULTS
GROUP BY 
    id
```

Answer (score 1):

would go with `UNNEST` + `ARRAY_AGG`:

```
select id, array_agg(elements) as unique_elements
from ( select distinct id, elements from RESULTS
       cross join unnest(id_arr) as t(elements)
       order by elements ) a
group by id
```